# Open nowhere dense set

Tags: general-topology

Statement: The only open, nowhere dense set is an empty set.
So, I'm not even sure whether this statement is true or false. I have a strong feeling it's true, but don't know how to prove it.
If we suppose the opposite: Let A be a not empty, open, nowhere dense set. Then "A closure" won't have an empty interior?? Any help?

Comment: What kind of space are we talking? A general topological space? A general metric space? Euclidean space?

Comment: $A$ is nowhere dense iff $\operatorname{int}(\overline{A})= \emptyset$. If $A$ is open, $A \subseteq \operatorname{int}(\overline{A})$. Conclude.

Comment: @Arthur that's irrelevant. But the tag also says metric-spaces, strangely enough.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma very nice.